# Legendre Transform Taking Too Long

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, coordinate-transformation

I am trying to perform Legendre transform on $x^2 \ln(1+x^{\frac{1}{3}}+x^{\frac{2}{3}})$ using this.

```
legendreTransform[f_, x_, y_] := 
Module[{k = Flatten[{x}], q = Flatten[{y}], h}, First[h /. 
Quiet[Solve[h == k.Grad[f, k] - f && q == Grad[f, k], 
  Append[k, h]], {Solve::incnst, Solve::ifun}]]]
Simplify[legendreTransform[a (Log[1 + c*x^(1/3) + d*x^(2/3)]), x, y],
Assumptions -> {Element[y, Reals]}]
```

And I did confirm this code gives correct Legendre transforms of $ e^x , x^2$.

However, it is taking very long for my computer (2 hours past, still no response after multiple tries) to run this with the expression above. This function is convex for x>0 , and this is the interval that I am interested in. Why is this the case?

Thank you very much for reading this question.

Comment: Likely it's the x^(1/3) causing problems, this is not a single valued function, and so it must choose which branch to calculate. Note that `legendreTransform[Log[1 + x^(1/3)], x, y]` is already multi-valued.

Comment: @bills then is it fine to add change the last part ' Assumptions -> {x>0, Element[x, Reals], Element[x, Reals]}' to solve that problem?

Comment: That won't really help because the branch cuts are occurring within the legendreTransform function, while the Assumptions are part of the Simplify function.

Comment: @bills Where may I find info. on choosing the branch on Mathematica? is there a built-in function for it?

Comment: legendreTransform[
 Refine[x^2 (Log[1 + x^(1/3) + x^(2/3)]), 
  Assumptions -> {x > 0, Element[x, Reals]}], x, y]                             doing this will not help either?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify that you want `Solve` to work over the reals, not the complexes.

```
legendreTransform[f_, x_, y_] := Module[{k = Flatten[{x}], q = Flatten[{y}], h}, 
    First[h /. Quiet[
       Solve[
          h == k.Grad[f, k] - f && q == Grad[f, k], 
          Append[k, h],
          Reals
       ], 
       {Solve::incnst, Solve::ifun}]
     ]
]
```

This will help it choose appropriate branches, and in this case produces an answer in little over a second.

```
 AbsoluteTiming[Simplify[legendreTransform[a (Log[1 + c*x^(1/3) + d*x^(2/3)]), x, y],
Assumptions -> {Element[y, Reals]}];]

 (* {1.33583, Null}   I suppressed output becaues the result is big and ugly *)
```

Comment: Thank you, but why do I get an error (returns h$1874, with 'Solve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve.')   When I plug in       a * x * (Log[1 + c*x^(1/3) + d*x^(2/3)])      as my function to this code? (all I did was multiplying x)

Comment: Unfortunately, transcendental equations are not always solvable.  Apparently, the one you get for that function falls into that camp.  (And you're getting `h$xxxx` because `Solve` isn't returning a rule becuase it failed, so `/.` never evaluates, so the First seems extracts your module variable `h` from the `/.`.)  You can try removing the `Reals` and see if that returns a result over the complexes, but it would litterally spend hours or more trying to establish a solution.  That may or may not work, and you may or may not be able to simplify the result to something usable over the reals.